# Get the current position of loop Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I am trying to get the position of the loop for use in another array.

Below I have two arrays. One of them has the loop. I want to get the Item of status at the same index, the loop is currently at in the first array.

```
let colours = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Green"]
let status = [1, 2, 2, 1]

func newFunc() {

for i in 1.. < colours.count { 

  print(colours[i]) 
  print(status[i])

 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `0..<` instead of `1..<` (In Swift, arrays start at index `0`)

Comment: try this `for i in 0 ..< colours.count` or `for i in 0..<colours.count` note the spaces.

Comment: `for i in colors.indices {` or use zip method `for (color, status) in zip(colours, status) {` `print(color)` `print(status)` `}`

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, your code is going to skip the first elements of both arrays, since Swift array indexing is 0-based.

Change it to `for i in 0..<colors.count`. (or better yet, `for i in colors.indicies` as Leo Dabus points out.)

The other problem is that your code will only work if the two arrays have the same number of elements. If there is any chance that the two arrays might have different numbers of elements you need to decide what to do about it. You could rewrite your for loop as

`for i in 0..<min(colours.count,status.count)`. That could would only loop through all the elements in the shorter array, and would ignore the extra elements in the longer array when the two arrays were different sizes.

### Edit:

As Leo Dabus points out in a comment on my answer, you can use `zip()` to combine your arrays:

```
for (color, aStatus) in zip(colors, status) {
   // Your code here
}
```

If you need an index for each item as well, you could use:

```
for (index, tuple) in zip(colors, status).enumerate {
   print("at index \(index), color is \(tuple.0), status = \(tuple.1)")
   // Your code here
}
```

Comment: `for i in colors.indices {` regarding your second suggestion `for (color, status) in zip(colours, status) {`

Comment: Good point. Iterating through a collection indices is a better way to do it.

Comment: @LeoDabus Does zip return n tuples, where `n = min(array1.count, array2.count)` when the arrays contain unequal numbers of elements? (I usually make sure the arrays have the same number of elements, so I don't recall how it handles unequal array counts.)

Comment: It will discard de excess of the longest